# how to get JQuery selector (Ex id) and one known DOM Object in single query

Tags: jquery

```
var $domObject = $("#element1");
//var $compain = $("#element2",element1);//its not working 
var $compain = $([element1,$("#element2")[0]]); // its working but two time call jquery||$.

$compain.hide();
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what result you actually want to get. Please add some more details to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Please show some html

Comment: Unclear... Please provide more details

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you correctly, you're trying to construct a jQuery entity containing two DOM nodes, recycling one of those nodes from a previous jQuery call.

This may be a case of premature optimization, especially if your elements have IDs: `$('#element1,#element2')` will be very quick, and is much more readable code than trying to recycle the earlier element.  Constructing a jQuery element takes a fraction of a millisecond; searching the DOM is the part that can be expensive, but for IDs that's much less of an issue.

But, assuming that those were just examples, and you're really dealing with complex class selectors that take a significant enough amount of processing time that it's really worth recycling the earlier element, you want to use jQuery's `.add()`:

```
var x = $('#element1'); // original element
var y = x.add($('#element2')); // original element concatenated with new element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your desired elements a specific class name, then make a selector using this:

```
var domObject = $('.desiredElements');
```

This way only your two elements with that classname will be passed in the jQuery selector.